# getting undefined when i run and for of loop and push the objects in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

so my code here is

```
const subAdmins = admin1.find({ status: 0 });
    //console.log(subAdmins);
    if (!subAdmins) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Server error. No admin found.",
      });
    } else {
      for await (let sub of subAdmins) {
        subAdminList.push({
          Name: sub.name,
          Admin_ID: sub.adminId,
          Client_Array: sub.clients,
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(subAdminList, "admin");
```

and the admin 1 schema looks like:

```
clients: [123, 234, 345],
name: MATT STEVENS,
adminId: PJ123,
```

But when i console.log the array subAdminList i am getting adminId and clients and undefined.

Comment: What do you even do when you do `find`? You check for status but what is that? It's not even a property on admin1

Comment: @Berlm yes it is a propery i forgot to mention that status is 0 for all the objects in schema

Comment: Whats the console output for console.log(subAdmins);?

Comment: is admin1 an array, or an object?

Comment: @Grumpy in subAdmins i am getting the schema i mean the result but when i run for-of loop i only get name and other 2 fields are undefined.

Comment: @Berlm admin 1 is schema it contains many objects

Comment: Show the console output, dont describe it.

Comment: First of all find will return the first admin with status == 0.
What you want is to use filter.

See here: 

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
and here
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter



Please look at this jsfiddle for an example with your code 

`https://jsfiddle.net/jsydv4fk/e`

Answer (score 1):

you're using the `find()` method wrong. You use it like this:

```js
const subAdmins = admin1.find(x => x.status === 0 );
```

Also, you probably want `filter()`, not `find()`. Find returns the first object found or `undefined`. The syntax is the same, so you can do:

```js
const subAdmins = admin1.filter(x => x.status === 0 );
```

Comment: find would also not work as subAdmins would not be a list but an object.

Comment: as he explained in his comments, thats just the schema, but `admin1` is actually an array

Comment: yeah I just got what you meant, and fixed that. Thanks!